# Unable to fetch Images from Firebase to Table View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, tableview

[Screenshot TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNry1.png)Is there a way to convert from `downloadURL`(link) to `UIImage` into my `TableViewController` ?

```
func loadPost() {                  
    Database.database().reference().child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let photoUrlString = userDict["photoUrl"] as! String
                let post = Posts(photoUrlString: photoUrlString)
                self.posts.append(post)
                print(self.posts)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }  
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this to download image. You can use this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func loadimage(_ url: URL)
{
    DispatchQueue.global().async { 
         if let data1 = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
           if let img = UIImage(data: data1){
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.imgView.image = img
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: in this method you just need to pass the image url and it will return a image on that url. once you got the image show on tableview cell you have.

Comment: Thanks! for the sample code! I did it with the 'do, loop' statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].photoUrl

        let postImage = posts[indexPath.row]
        if let photoUrl = URL(string: postImage.photoUrl)
        {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: photoUrl)
                cell.imageView?.image = UIImage (data: data)
            } catch {
                print("")
            }
        }

       return cell
    }
```